# Как достать значение элементов из массива JSON на bash?

Tags: linux, json, api, bash

У меня есть API, который выводит массив Json такого формата: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне с помощью bash вывести данные из ключей "name" первых двух словарей?
я знаю как логически это сделать на python, но как на bash не могу понять, подскажите пожалуйста. (в моем примере ключ "title")

Comment: B bash есть регулярные выражения

Comment: В баше «есть» grep . Но вообще идея парсить json регулярками прокатывает только если это одноразовая задача. Для нормального решения всё же лучше что-то что понимает json.

Comment: Поэксперементируй с jq https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/

Comment: `grep -oPm2 '(?="title": ")[^"]*(?=")'` в таком виде должно сработать

Comment: Советчикам использования `grep` могу сказать — не издевайтесь над людьми.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

для работы с json в консоли используйте утилиту [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)
которая является лучшей в своём роде.

через файл:

```
jq -r '.[0,1].title' file.json
```

через переменную:

```
echo "$JsonVar" | jq -r '.[0,1].title'
```

или вот более конкретный ответ(из комментария) когда json получаем из сети:

```
curl -s "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos" | jq -r '.[0,1].title'
```

---

п.с.

можно конечно упороться и написать типа *на bash* используя grep, sed или тот же awk, как пример:

```
awk -F'"' '/"title": /{print $4}' file.json | head -2
```

но это всё не есть bash ))

из вышеперечисленного к башу относится разве что тока труба( "|" - pipe )

grep, sed, awk это внешние утилиты, и даже утилита head - хотя она и входит в состав coreutils но это не есть bash, а всего лишь базовый набор **linux** утилит, не bash.

Запуская в интерпретаторе bash утилиту type (которая как раз является *встроенная* в bash) можно в этом убедится:

```
$ type -t type grep sed awk head echo
builtin
file
file
file
file
builtin

$ type --help
...
-t  output a single word which is one of `alias', `keyword',
  `function', `builtin', `file' or `', if NAME is an alias,
  shell reserved word, shell function, shell builtin, disk file,
  or not found, respectively
```

Comment: jq -r '.[0,1].title' file.json а возможно ли сделать аналогично, только с переменной(в которой массив), т.е. без файла?

Comment: @kose1n,

без проблем

 `echo "$JsonVar" | jq -r '.[0,1].title'`

Comment: говорит, что не может индексировать массив с помощью строки "title"  :(

Comment: @kose1n,

выложите свой json текстом а не картинкой, возможно где-то опечатки

Comment: Кажется у меня всё получилось и я всё понял, спасибо Вам за ответы!

Comment: @kose1n,

все вроде работает, даже напрямую курлом по ссылке вытянул json (добавил в ответе)